# Mocking a Callback Function in Jest Doesn't Execute as Expected

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am currently testing a React application that incorporates the Autodesk Viewer.

I'm attempting to mock a function (`Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer`) with a callback using Jest. Inside this callback, another function is invoked (`Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D`), which I also want to mock.

Here's what the code snippet looks like:

Code:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (/* some condition which passes */) {
      console.log('before entering function') /* This log gets printed */
      Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ accessToken: auth.token.access_token }, () => {
        console.log('ok'); /* This log does not get printed */
        const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(viewerContainerRef.current);
        viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, handleGeometryLoaded);
        setViewer(viewer);
        viewer.start();
      });
    }
  }, [auth, location])
```

Jest Code:

```
// Mocking
global.Autodesk = {
  Viewing: {
    GuiViewer3D: jest.fn((ref) => {
      return {
        start: jest.fn(),
        started: true,
      }
    }),
    Extension: jest.fn(),
    ToolInterface: jest.fn(),
    Initializer: jest.fn((access_token, callback) => {
      console.log('Hello, I should be called before the callback') // This is never printed
      callback();
    }),
  },
};

// more code, not relevant for this problem

// test
  test('redirects to viewer when version is clicked', async () => {
    const router = createMemoryRouter(routesConfig, { 
      initialEntries: ['/index/viewer/hub_id/project_id/folder_id']
    });

    render(
      <AuthProvider>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </AuthProvider>
    );

    await screen.findByRole('checkbox');
    await waitFor(() => user.click(screen.getByRole('checkbox')));
    await waitFor(() => user.click(screen.getByText(/load/i)));
    
    expect(screen.getByRole('checkbox')).toBeChecked();
    expect(Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer).toHaveBeenCalledWith({accessToken: '123'}, expect.any(Function));
    expect(Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Now, the first assertion passes. So I can verify that the function `Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer` is indeed called. However, the callback inside the Initializer never gets executed as the second assertion fails. In an attempt to debug this, I added console.log statements and observed that the console.log statement inside the mocked Initializer isn't displayed.

It's important to note that other print statements during the test execution are working as expected, and the code works perfectly in a Browser environment.